# Loop through files on Synology SSH command line

Tags: ssh, synology

I have Synology with ipkg installed, and mkvmerge working.

When I use

```
/opt/bin/mkvmerge -o /path_to_file/filename.added_subs.mkv 
--default-track 0 --language 0:eng /path_to_file/filename.srt     
/path_to_file/filename.mkv
```

This works perfectly, and the file gets remuxed with the subtitles added.

But because I have many (many) files I want to do this with, I;d like to run a batch for this.

I've found this line to explain what I want to do:

```
FOR %A IN (/path_to_files/*.mkv) DO /opt/bin/mkvmerge -o /path_to_files/%~nA.added_subs.mkv --default-track 0 --language 0:eng /path_to_files/%~nA.srt /path_to_files/%~nA.mkv
```

But the Synology won't accept the FOR ... IN command.

Anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Most likely because you are using the wrong shell scripting commands. I would assume without even Googling that it uses BASH or some other NIX shell.

Comment: You're right @Squashman, you've put me in the right direction. It uses Busybox. Looks like I have to found the command for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
FILES=/path/*.mkv
for f in $FILES 
do /opt/bin/mkvmerge -o ${f%.*}.EN.mkv --default-track 0 --language 0:en ${f%.*}.srt ${f%.*}.mkv
done
```